# Disable mouse in synaptic touchpad with libinput

Tags: touchpad, synaptic, xinput, trackpoint

Is there any way to stop touchpad moving my mouse but still have buttons working with libinput (ubuntu 15.10 with xserver-xorg-input-libinput)? The same effect used to be achieved with setting AreaTopEdge=9999 in synaptic.

my env:

```
xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Rapoo Rapoo Wireless Audio                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
root@localhost:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d# xinput list-props 13
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (279): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (280): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (281):   1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Accel Speed (283): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (284): 0.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (285):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (263): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (264):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (265):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (287): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (288): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (289):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (290):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (291):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (292): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (293):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (294):    1, 0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (295):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (296):    1
    Device Node (266):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (267):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (297):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (268):    0
    Synaptics Off (501):    2
    Synaptics Tap Time (742):   1000
```

Please  note there is no Synaptics Finger property. I hoped that setting it to 100 release, 1000 touch, 200 press would solve my problem, but no luck...

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet? I’m very interested in a solution. I tried setting acceleration to -1 but it doesn’t disable movement either. Though it makes movement much slower so it might help a bit. xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Accel Speed" -1

Comment: No, but I found that it's possible to disable it in BIOS. Buttons still work. I tried to apply all sorts of options found on http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html,  like "xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 13 "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255" but no effect at all

Comment: Short update: I managed to disable movement quick&dirty in source code. I uncommented line 920 (tp_motion_history_push(t))  in libinput 1.0.3’s evdev_mt_touchpad.c, then built and overwrote the existing libinput .so file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Michael](https://askubuntu.com/users/477928/michael)'s comment on your question from Dec 16 '15, I built a script which patches and installs libinput in order to entirely disable touchpad movements.
The script is available from https://github.com/faf0/thinkpad-scripts/blob/master/16.04/libinput-disable-touchpad-movements.sh.
Simply clone the github repository and then execute the `libinput-disable-touchpad-movements.sh` script to carry out the installation.
Unfortunately, I did not find a way to set the xinput properties of the touchpad to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired result by recompiling the libinput libraries from source with minor changes.

file:

```
evdev-mt-touchpad-buttons.c
```

function:

```
tp_post_clickpadbutton_buttons()
```

in each location where 'button' is set to eg 'BTN_LEFT' replace 'BTN_LEFT' with 0

Compile and install